# initial capacity of HashMap 16 instead of 8 or 32

Tags: java, hashmap

Why is the initial capacity of HashMap 16 instead of 8 or 32. When the number of elements is uncertain, use the initial default capacity of 16 or how much?

Comment: I don’t see the point of your Question. You can pass to the constructor any initial capacity you want.

Comment: Apparently the designers determined that was the best default compromise.